# How can I force my Bokeh DataTable to be sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I have a Bokeh DataTable that I am rendering using `bokeh serve` and I want it to begin sorted without the user having to click on the column header. I'd like to have the rows sorted such that the birthday dates are in ascending order. My current code looks like:

```py
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn, DateFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from pandas import DataFrame

import datetime

# data is usually fetched from somewhere else but this is the same format
data = [
    ('dan', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 16, 21, 30)),\
    ('joel', datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 21, 21, 30)),\
    ('jeff', datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 21, 30))]

ne = DataFrame()
ne['Name'] = [x[0] for x in data]
ne['Birthday'] = [x[1] for x in data]

source = ColumnDataSource(ne)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field='Name', title='Name'),
    TableColumn(field='Birthday', title='Birthday', formatter=DateFormatter())
]

dt = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)

curdoc().add_root(column(dt))
```

Comment: Provide a full working example, including the imports.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel fixed, how's that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best approach, but I got the result you are looking for by pre sorting the DataFrame by adding the following line

`ne.sort_values('Birthday', inplace=True)`

before

`source = ColumnDataSource(ne)`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: Hmm.. must be a way to have this done by the table itself..